# how to post facebook user wall/ page status by a single user only no app install for other users

Tags: facebook, post, status, facebook-page

I am working on a site and i need to post page links from that site to a special user wall or page if something is published on it which means i only need one user to post that question.

the problem which i am facing is access token since i am not trying to show facebook login page in front of website traffic. its not like sharing on user wall we are basically trying to post status on a page automatically so any help for this problem will be appreciated.

i am using the following code which seems to work fine as long as the access token for the page is valid but i need to make something permanent so that i can add all the info in the php code hardcoded and it work for some weeks at-least without changing the api key or token

```
$appid = 'code';
$appsecret = 'code';
$wall= $pageId = 'code';

$token='page token';

$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => $appid, 'secret' => $appsecret, 'cookie' => true));

$params=array( 'message' => $msg,'name' => $title, 'caption' => $title, 'link' =>$uri,'description' => $desc, 'picture' => $pic, 'access_token' => $token,'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link)) );

$result = $facebook->api($wall.'/feed/','post',$params);
```

if i make token from the graph api debug page then it works fine but after some time i got the message "OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

i am really desperate to find something solid for it.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a backend script (maybe a cron job using the FB PHP-SDK) that runs as the special user and makes the desired FB api calls.  For this, you will want to use a [long-lived access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/), which needs to be renewed every 60 days.  You might also try your FB api calls using an [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/), which do not expire but also do not support all FB publishing and other operations.

Comment: Hi can you help me out here. i am trying but clearly i am missing something here.

I am using this code below but while trying to get extented tocken i am getting 190 and wrong auth token message. please check this code below

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $appid,
 'secret' => $appsecret,
 'cookie' => true,
 ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Contact Facebook and get token
 if ($user) {
 // you're logged in, and we'll get user acces token for posting on the wall
 try {

echo $access_token= $facebook->getAccessToken();

Comment: Hi @donn lee

thanks for the advice. I was able to do it but i think i accidentally did the token extend part but i am wondering why my token code is showing expiry = never status in facebook debug tool. currently the site is working fine and app is posting on the page on the behalf of the page so all looks good but is that ok with expiry status = never

and thanks for the extend token part.

Comment: You might have the offline_access migration disabled for your app. See your app's migrations settings in the Advanced section. After December 5, offline access tokens will be disabled for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To post to someones wall (or perform any action with the open graph) you must be authenticated with facebook as somebody in their graph or an application that they have granted permission to.

You should look at the permissions that can be set using the oauth scope attribute...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

To me it looks like they will need to grant your application publish_stream if you want to write to their friends walls as well as the user that you are authenticated as.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: no i just need this app for one user. which is a website. whenever something publish on it. i want it to post on the facebook page as well since the article publishing will be in the admin side and their is no place for asking for a facebook login in the whole process.